# AESBase64 encryption decryption from java to golang conversation

Tags: java, go, encryption, base64, aes

I want to rewrite the following code from java to golang.
Here mostly I am looking for a function which can work same as `byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode((encryptedText));`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESBase64UsedForPartners {
    private final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
    private final String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES";
    static String SecretKey = "$sgettng@&Key%";
public String encrypt(String plainText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] plainTextbytes = plainText.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(SecretKey);
    byte[] str = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encrypt(plainTextbytes, keyBytes, keyBytes));
    return new String(str);
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key, byte[] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    plainText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    return plainText;
}

public String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws KeyException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException {
    byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode((encryptedText));
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(SecretKey);
    return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), characterEncoding);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
    cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    return cipherText;
}


private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] parameterKeyBytes = key.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
    return keyBytes;
}

public static void main(String a[]) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    String str = new AESBase64UsedForPartners().encrypt("Text");
    System.out.println("Encrypted---->" + str);
    System.out.println(new AESBase64UsedForPartners().decrypt(str));
}

}
```

Comment: The posted line simply performs a Base64 decoding, see e.g. [encoding/base64](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64). Regarding the port from Java to Go, please post your latest Go code.

Comment: Just a security note: the Java code is **unsecure** as it uses the same init vector as the key. Better use a randomly generated IV and secondly it could be a good idea to run a password key derivation like PBKDF2 for the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [encoding/base64](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64) package for decoding Base64 encoded strings:

```
decoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
```

Comment: I have tried your solution. But not get the proper response for some reason.

https://play.golang.org/p/4_Tgt5ix6zX

Comment: That sounds like a new question already. Perhaps you can post a new question with both Java and Go versions included in the question itself.